# button value passing as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I apologize for the simple question, I'm new to react and I have yet to find a solution for this problem. When clicked, I'm trying to retrieve the value for each button. The value repeatedly comes back as undefined. What am I doing wrong? I greatly appreciate your help!

```
    class BottomListFilter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleButton = this.handleButton.bind(this);
    }

    handleButton = (evt) => {
      console.log(evt.target.value);  
    };

    render() {
        const listFilter = this.props.initialAdvisorList.map((filter) => 
            <li key={filter.id}>
                <a href="#">{filter.location}</a>
            </li>
        );
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button  
                    value='location'
                    onClick={this.handleButton}
                    >
                        <h2>Choose by location</h2>
                    </button>
                    <button
                    value='state'
                    onClick={this.handleButton}
                    >
                        <h2>Choose by state</h2>
                    </button>
                    <button
                    value='practice'
                    onClick={this.handleButton}
                    >
                        <h2>Choose by practice</h2>
                    </button>
                    <button
                    value='topic'
                    onClick={this.handleButton}
                    >
                        <h2>Choose by topic</h2>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        {listFilter}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a debugger inside your handleButton and checking what all the attributes of the evt are? Perhaps target and value aren't what you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I found the value inside `evt.target.parentNode.value`. Would it be appropriate to access the value in that way?

Comment: Consider what props the element passes to an event when choosing an element. I can't guess your purpose behind picking button, but is there a more semantic element you could use that traditionally passes value?

Comment: handleButton ===== handleButton() = () ...

Comment: @ZeRubeus - what does that even mean?

Comment: missed the () when declaring the class method ..., I'm not sure it's requaried just try it .. who knows ..

Comment: Could you try `this.refs.buttonFirst.val `and  `<button
                    value='topic' ref='buttonFirst'
                    onClick={this.handleButton}
                    >
                        <h2>Choose by topic</h2>
                    </button>`? In your handleButton you would be able to et the value of the button.

Comment: instead of hundleButton = () .. stuff .. try hundleButton(ev) {} as a class mlethode

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do evt.target.parentNode.value and it will work in this case. It may be just me but I find that solution against the spirit of React as it's reminisce of traversing the DOM (JQuery days).

Passing the value to handleButton function is much cleaner and more flexible:

```
<button onClick={this.handleButton.bind(null, 'location')}>
    <h2>Choose by location</h2>
</button>
```

Now your handleButton looks like this:

```
handleButton(value, event) {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(event);
}
```

In this case, you don't really need "event" anymore and you could easily do handleButton(value) but I have included it just for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify your `handleButton` situation. it doesn't need to be a method. (in the code below, i also stripped away the `ul`, just to isolate the issue.)

i don't think this is what was causing the problem, though. most likely, the problem was not a React issue but just a simple DOM issue. `event.target` means "the lowest-level node where the event took place". if you clicked on the `h2`, that node is the `h2`, which *has no `value` property*.

just don't use an `h2`. put the text directly inside the button. also shown in the code sample.

```js
var handleButton = evt => {
      console.log(evt.target.value)  
    }

class BottomListFilter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleButton = this.handleButton.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return(
        <div>
            <button  
            value='location'
            onClick={handleButton}
            >
                Choose by location
            </button>
            <button
            value='state'
            onClick={handleButton}
            >
                Choose by state
            </button>
            <button
            value='practice'
            onClick={handleButton}
            >
                Choose by practice
            </button>
            <button
            value='topic'
            onClick={handleButton}
            >
                Choose by topic
            </button>
          </div>

        );
    }
}
```